# How to read TimeStamp from MySQL database and check if equal to todays date

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

Read TimeStamp from MySQL database and compare with today's date, `DateDeposited`, format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt`.

```
MySqlCommand cmd1 = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd1.CommandText = ("select * from deposits where MemberID = @MemberID");
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", lblmemberID.Text);

//DataReader
MySqlDataReader da;
conn.Open();

da = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

if (da.Read())
{
    // DateDeposited is timestamp
    if(da["DateDeposited"].ToString() == DateTime.Today.Date.ToString())
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Deposit already recorded");
         conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this: `da["DateDeposited"].ToString().Equals(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss");)`

Comment: I am comparing da["DateDeposited"].ToString() to todays(dd-MM-yyyy) date,please note DateDeposited in database is timestamp in format(yyyy-MM-dd)

Comment: Yes and that is why I am formatting the current date to the MySQL timestamp.

Comment: Not comparing it to Datetime.Now am comparing to todays Date in format(dd/MM/yyyy)

Comment: See this example to convert MySQL TimeStamp to C# Datetime only with Date part: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bJzbi7

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a way to find out whether the timestamp is between 00:00 and 23:59:59 local time today.

This query works. And because you use `TIMESTAMP` data types and you do the date comparison inside the MySQL server, you don't have to worry about different timezone settings on the MySQL machine and the machine running your C# code.

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN (DATE(DateDeposited)) = CURDATE() THEN 'yes'
            ELSE 'No' END IsItToday 
       FROM deposits where MemberID = @MemberID
```

Why does it work? `DATE(ts)` retrieves the date of a timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

Was able to resolve by adding hidden datetimepicker and reading its value and checked if its equal to timestamp date from database

```
MySqlCommand cmd1 = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd1.CommandText = ("select * from deposits where MemberID=@MemberID and DepositAmount=@DepositAmount and (DATE_FORMAT(DateDeposited,'%Y-%m-%d')= CURRENT_DATE())");
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtname.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtphone.Text.ToString());
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepositAmount", txtamount.Text.ToString());
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", txtrate.Text.ToString());
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", lblmemberID.Text);

//DataReader
MySqlDataReader da;
conn.Open();

da = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

if (da.Read())
{
string s;
DateTime converted = Convert.ToDateTime(da["DateDeposited"]);
s = converted.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
if ( da["MemberID"].ToString()==lblmemberID.Text && da["DepositAmount"].ToString()== txtamount.Text.ToString()&& s.ToString()==dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
{
 MessageBox.Show("Deposit already recorded", "Warning!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
conn.Close();
}
}
```